# PM2 EPERM, Operation not permitted on call initgroups

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu-16.04, pm2

I have install pm2 globally
`sudo pm2 install -g`
pm2 start server.js

pm2 status (gives this output)
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬───────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem       │ user    │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼───────────┼─────────┼──────────┤
│ server   │ 0  │ fork │ 10094 │ online │ 0       │ 85s    │ 0%  │ 44.7 MB   │ ubuntu │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴───────────┴─────────┴──────────┘

When pm2 log 0
we get following error

1|server   | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 14:35:03 GMT zap2it:server Server now running on localhost:4040

1|server   | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 14:35:03 GMT zap2it:server spawning worker #53

1|server   | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: EPERM, Operation not permitted on call initgroups

1|server   | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: ubuntu is not accessible

What permission I need for pm2 to run or where I can look for errors?
Can I install and run pm2 using root?

Comment: have you tried `pm2 log server`? and `sudo pm2 log server`. Moreover install pm2 with sudo is a bad Idea.

Comment: 1|server | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 14:35:03 GMT zap2it:server Server now running on localhost:4040

1|server | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 14:35:03 GMT zap2it:server spawning worker #53

1|server | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: EPERM, Operation not permitted on call initgroups

1|server | 2018-01-23 14:35 +00:00: ubuntu is not accessible

Comment: Have you exactly typed:
`sudo npm install pm2 -g` then `sudo pm2 start app.js`?
Anyway we have just published a 2.9.3 with the hotfix

Comment: v2.9.3 worked thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PM2 logs can be found at `<HOME>/.pm2/logs/` and you should be able to install and run it using root, although this is not recommended (as stated in the comments by [savior123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4008203/saviour123)).

I've just run into the same issue and error messages as you a while ago - although not running PM2 with `sudo` - and solved it by updating PM2 version (from 2.9.2 to 2.9.3), as commented by [Unitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526390/unitech)

Comment: v2.9.2 seems to had issue. v2.9.1 and v2.9.3 seems fine. thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 3):

you must execute pm2 update like:
sudo npm install -g pm2
pm2 update
pm2 start server.js

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue on windows by going to the services and stop the pm2 service from running and at my terminal, I did the pm2 start app.js and everything ran fine

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32421389)